# Docker: how to connect two bridges

Tags: networking, docker, bridge

As you know after Docker 1.9 we can create bridges to connect containers.

I have created two custom bridges:  bridge A `172.18.0.1` and bridge B `172.19.0.1`.

Now I have a container1 on bridge A, and a container2 on bridge B called "mailServer".

The container1 needs to reach container2 by a DNS, how should I do this? Because they are on different bridges so they cannot talk to each other. Do I need a router and can I achieve this by Docker?

This is a new feature of Docker and I didn't find much information. Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can try making use of the veth peer so that you can connect two bridges. Make sure you are rename  and  names respectively with the one you configured.

```
ip link add veth0 type veth peer name veth1
ifconfig veth0 up
ifconfig veth1 up
brctl addif <D1-A-Bridge> veth0
brctl addif <D2-A-Bridge> veth1
```

Comment: if Bridge A and Bridge B is not in a same subnet.the connection is not useful.

Answer (score 15):

To connect container2 to container1 you can also connect it to bridgeB

```
$ docker network connect bridgeB container1
```

This will allow container1 to connect to container2 by IP address, DNS names would still have to be updated manually afaik.

More information in the Docker networking guide [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/work-with-networks/).

Comment: Is there a more semantic way to connect two custom bridge networks? `docker network connect NETWORK1 NETWORK2` is not supported. Is connecting two custom bridge networks bad idea (might be bad idea since it's not supported)? Why?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect two bridges, you can use a pair of
patch ports with open v-switch .  The follow example creates bridges br0 and br1, adds eth0 and tap0 to br0, adds tap1 to br1, and then connects br0 and br1 with a pair of patch ports.

```
   ovs-vsctl add-br br0
   ovs-vsctl add-port br0 eth0
   ovs-vsctl add-port br0 tap0
   ovs-vsctl add-br br1
   ovs-vsctl add-port br1 tap1
   ovs-vsctl \
       -- add-port br0 patch0 \
       -- set interface patch0 type=patch options:peer=patch1 \
       -- add-port br1 patch1 \
       -- set interface patch1 type=patch options:peer=patch0
```

Answer (score 0):

set Forward chain in filter table ,allow Bridge-A and Bridge-B forward.if you want to access internet,set masqurade in Postrouting chain of nat table